# how to fill struct values with exec.Command().Output() command in Golang?

Tags: go

I've written following code in Golang and I need to pass the output values into dateStruct, can someone please help me how can I do it or even if there is other better way to pass terminal's command output into a struct?

```
type dateStruct struct {
    day string
    month string
    year string
}

func main()  {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)

    fmt.Println(dateStruct{})
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? exec.Command().Output() varies widely depending on the command you're executing. If your end goal is to get the current date, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: As @CeriseLimón mentioned, the format of the output is critical. I assume the `date` was just an example. Ideally if you can get the command to output in parsable format (JSON, YAML etc.) - then you can use a `Pipe` on the command's `stdout`, and pass the pipe's `io.Reader` directly into the appropriate `Decoder` (`json.Decoder`, `yaml.Decoder` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the output of a command can be anything (it can be any command), you will have to create mapping code.

The assignment in the struct can look like this:

```
ds:=&dateStruct{
day: parseDay(out),
month: parseMonth(out),
year: parseYear(out),
}
```

Comment: exactly, the output of command can be any command. for this case I have only 4 specific commands and was looking to find if there is any other way to run the command and get the output.

Comment: Also look at the commands itself: Some will provide you with structured output (like json, yaml or xml), making your life a lot easier